# Facebook Marketing API Ads Insights to CSV in Python

Tags: python, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-business-sdk

How to export the response of Facebook Marketing API Ads insights to CSV.

Below are my code and the response from it.

```
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount

app_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_token = 'xxxxxxxxx'
FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id, app_secret, access_token)

params = {'time_range': {'since': '2020-01-01', 'until': '2020-12-25'},
          'time_increment':1,
          'level': 'adset',
          'sort': ['spend_descending'],
          'export_format':'csv'}
fields = ['account_name',
          'campaign_name',
          'campaign_id',
          'adset_name',
          'adset_id',
          'impressions',
          'clicks',
          'cpm',
          'spend',
          'ctr']

insights = AdAccount('act_332828570147114').get_insights(params=params, fields=fields)
print(insights)
```

Response is

```
[<AdsInsights> {
    "account_name": "xxx",
    "adset_id": "xxx",
    "adset_name": "xxx",
    "campaign_id": "xxx",
    "campaign_name": "xxx",
    "clicks": "xxx",
    "cpm": "xxx",
    "ctr": "xxx",
    "date_start": "xxx",
    "date_stop": "xxx",
    "impressions": "xxx",
    "spend": "xxx"
}, <AdsInsights> {
    "account_name": "xxx",
    "adset_id": "xxx",
    "adset_name": "xxx",
    "campaign_id": "xxx",
    "campaign_name": "xxx",
    "clicks": "xxx",
    "cpm": "xxx",
    "ctr": "xxx",
    "date_start": "xxx",
    "date_stop": "xxx",
    "impressions": "xxx",
    "spend": "xxx"
}]
```

How can we export this response to CSV format? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount

app_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_token = 'xxxxxxxxx'
FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id, app_secret, access_token)

params = {'time_range': {'since': '2020-01-01', 'until': '2020-12-25'},
          'time_increment':1,
          'level': 'adset',
          'sort': ['spend_descending'],
          'export_format':'csv'}
fields = ['account_name',
          'campaign_name',
          'campaign_id',
          'adset_name',
          'adset_id',
          'impressions',
          'clicks',
          'cpm',
          'spend',
          'ctr']

insights = list(AdAccount('act_332828570147114').get_insights(params=params, fields=fields))
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=fields)
for field in fields:
    df["{}".format(field)]=[x['{}'.format(field)] for x in insights]

df.to_csv("insights.csv",index=False)
```

Interact with the adinsights objects as dictionaries and add them to dataframe before saving as csv!